# Take the element in a list that satisfy a condition

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a `List[Either[Error, Satisfaction]]`, and I need to take the first element in that list that `isRight`. If there are no elements that satisfy `isRight`, then I should return the last `Error`.

For now I've thought on a `takeWhile(_.isLeft)`, find the size of this last list, and then get the `n`th element in the original list, with `n` being the size of the first-lefts list, but I think there's a better solution for this.

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might `reduce` the list like so:

```
lst.reduceLeft((a,b) => if (a.isRight) a else b)
```

The result will be the first `Right` element or, if there is none, the final `Left` element.

Comment: This is very clever. Only downside I can see is it won't "short-circuit" if a `Right` element is found early on. But the only way I can think of doing that would be significantly more code.

Comment: @JoeK, I agree. Early termination would be nice. It can be done via recursion but, as you said, more code. In fact, I was thinking that _this_ is too verbose. Since `Either[]` is now right-biased we ought to be able to do something like `a orElse b`. Maybe in Scala 2.13.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, which has the dual problem to @jwvh's answer: if `rest` is empty, it has to go over the list again.

```
val (lefts, rest) = list.span(_.isLeft)
rest.headOption.getOrElse(lefts.last) 
// or orElse(lefts.lastOption) if list can be empty
```

And the recursive solution without either problem for completeness (assuming non-empty list):

```
def foo(list: List[Either[Error, Satisfaction]]) = list match {
  case x :: tail => if (x.isRight || tail.isEmpty) x else foo(tail)
}
```

Not *that* much more code.

Comment: You know, I just started thinking about it along similar lines: `lst.find(_.isRight).getOrElse(lst.last)`

Comment: Second time in a row I give an answer which can be simplified a lot. Time to get some sleep instead :)